# Query complicated array in a JSONB in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB field value:

```
{
   "status":200,
   "response":{
      "page":1,
      "limit":10,
      "total":4,
      "orders":[
         {
            "id":40201
         },
         {
            "id":40111
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How do I query for the orders array object with id=40201?

Im trying to query for all rows with response->orders->[id: 40201]

Comment: The "orders array" is simply `the_column -> 'response' -> 'orders'` not sure what you mean with "orders array with id = ..." there are multiple IDs in the array. What exactly is the output you want?

Comment: Im trying to query for all rows with response->orders->[id: 40201]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e2baefc0ba4907472deb81585a5283e7)

If you know that this is the first object in your array (zero-based!):

```
SELECT
    yourjson -> 'response' -> 'orders' -> 0
```

If not, you have to expand your array into one row per element with `jsonb_array_elements()` and filter each row:

```
SELECT 
    elems.value
FROM 
    yourtable,
    jsonb_array_elements(yourjson -> 'response' -> 'orders') elems
WHERE
    elems ->> 'id' = '40201'
```

[documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: just to clarify, Im trying to query for all rows with response->orders->[id: 40201]

Comment: @Hackbyrd Then you'll need the second way: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dd5f8dfb91f2ba9ce98245657f6e9bac

Answer (score 1):

I would use an `exists` query for that:

```
select *
from the_table
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(the_json_column -> 'response' -> 'orders') as x (o)
              where x.o ->> 'id' = 40201');
```

alternatively with the `@>` contains operator:

```
select *
from the_table
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(the_json_column -> 'response' -> 'orders') as x (o)
              where x.o @> '{"id" : 40201}';
```